# How do I display MarginFi Leding/Borrowing pools in my ui?

Tags: data, sdk, frontend

I'm digging into this [mrgn-ts](https://github.com/mrgnlabs/mrgn-ts) library and I can't seem to figure out how to fetch all the available lending/borrowing pools and display some data about them, like asset price, APY, available funds to borrow etc.. , on my React front end. Essentially I just want to show my users information about all the available pools in this protocol.

There's really no documentation about the SDK and no examples I could find on how to use it. I tried installing and tinkering with the client `@mrgnlabs/marginfi-client-v2` but that doesn't seem to provide access to the pools or banks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this out https://github.com/mrgnlabs/pulsar-example/blob/main/index.ts
Its shows some basic examples